# Get chosen button from loop typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6

[image]I have a array of person I loop it, It is hard to explain for me I want somthing like this

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
{{person.name}} {{person.surname}}
<button class="btn {{mmm}}" (click)="chosePerson(person.id)">chose</button>
```

each user has own button when I click button it should change exactly that button's color

In my person.component.ts

```
persons: IPersons[];
mmm: any = 'btn-success';

chosePerson(id: number) {
    this.persons.forEach(element => {
        if (element.id === id) {
            element.clicked = true;
            this.mmm = 'btn-danger';
        } else {
            element.clicked = false;
            this.mmm = 'btn-success';
        }
    });
}
```

In my person.model.ts

```
export interface IPerson{
id?: number;
name?: string;
surname?: string;
age?: number;
self_number?: string;
parent_number?: string;
home_number?: string;
photoContentType?: string;
photo?: any;
clicked?: boolean;}

export class Person implements IPerson{
constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public surname?: string,
    public age?: number,
    public self_number?: string,
    public parent_number?: string,
    public home_number?: string,
    public photoContentType?: string,
    public photo?: any
) {}}
```

Comment: Feel free to provide StackBlitz if the problem is not solved! So any one try!

Comment: ok of course I'll do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra field to each person object. Name it, for example, `clicked`.

And then use the `ngClass`-directive in your HTML. This will add the additional class only when `clicked` of this particular person is set to true.

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
    {{person.name}} {{person.surname}}
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'mmm': person.clicked==true}" 
    (click)="chosePerson(person.id)">chose</button>
```

And in your TS-file loop through the list and set the clicked-field to true. At the same time set all the others back to false;

```
chosePerson(id: number) {
    this.persons.forEach(element => {
        if (element.id === id) {
            element.clicked = true;
        } else {
            element.clicked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: In html: Checks JavaScript referenced variables and fields to be valid ones. The validation works in JavaScript, html or jsp files

Comment: in ts component: Property 'clicked' does not exist on type 'Person'.

Comment: When or where do you define your person-object? Do you have a model for it? You have to add the field `checked` in your model of the person object as `checked: boolean` in order to be able to use it.

Comment: Does the solved-mark mean, that it works now for you?

Comment: O thanks a lot Lynx 242, handed buddy. I did it, my mistake was a wrong using ngClass. Insted of use btn-danger in class I tried to use variable 'mmm' so I added to simple class class="btn btn-success" and to ngClass I added [ngClass]="{'btn-danger': abituriyent.clicked === true} so it is worked